# Instantiate Spawns Object Away from Source?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

So what I'm trying to do is spawn a prefab of smaller cubes onto the exact same position and rotation of a big cube so it 'breaks apart'. When I hit space, the big cube disappears as intended, but the smaller cubes instantiate from a distance.

[Here's a .gif of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpfaw.gif)

```
 void Update () {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
         {
             Instantiate(explo, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
             Destroy(gameObject);
         }
         Debug.Log("The Rotation");
         Debug.Log(explo.transform.rotation);
         Debug.Log("The Position");
         Debug.Log(explo.transform.position);
     }
```

Debug Log:

```
 The Rotation
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
 The Position
 (-5.5, -2.4, 3.5)
```

This is an extremely simple script and I've spent 2 days trying to find a similar problem to mine, but they all include Quaternion, which is not similar to my problem.

EDIT: Changing gameObject.transform.rotation to Quaternion.identity seems to entirely reset the rotation of the object.

EDIT2: 'explo' is defined before 'void start' as 'public GameObject explo', and is assigned via the Unity Editor.

Comment: What is `explo` defined as and what game object do you have this script attached to?

Comment: The script is attached to an object titled "Big Cube", and 'explo' is a prefab that I attached via the unity editor, it's called "Smaller Cubes".

Comment: Do you have any scripts attached to `explo`?  Is this your exact code?  I'm confused how `explo.localScale` compiles because I think it should be `explo.transform.localScale`

Comment: `explo` has no scripts attached to it, and changing `explo.localScale` to `explo.transform.localScale` still returns the same result.

(If there was an error before I hadn't noticed, it still compiled without error?)

Comment: Try using `Quaternion.Identity` instead of `gameObject.transform.rotation` in your `Instantiate`

Comment: That returned [this](http://i.imgur.com/lSPXoBg.gifv). Seems to of reset the rotation?

Comment: Please update your post with your entire script.

Comment: Edited to show what I've changed. There is nothing else written in the script besides `void start`, these are the only lines written.

Comment: If there's nothing else in the script, where is `explo` defined?

Comment: A side note (I don't think this is related to the problem); `Debug.Log(explo.transform.position);` is showing the position of your prefab, not of the position of the instance of that prefab that you added to your scene.  If you want to see the position of the object in your scene, you want something like `GameObject cube = Instantiate(explo, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;` and then show the position of `cube`.

Comment: @BenRubin 'explo' is defined from a code before 'void start': 'public Transform explo' Also, I've been at work so sorry for the slow responses! Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: No worries.  Try defining `explo` as a `GameObject` instead of a `Transform` (making sure to re-assign your prefab in the Unity editor after changing it).  I did a quick mock up of a scene and used your code and the new cube spawned in the same place that the old cube was, so your problem must related to something other than that piece of code.

Comment: [Here is the full code.](http://i.imgur.com/GCUtuSF.png). I'm still managing to get the same issue. [Here is Big Cube](http://i.imgur.com/ks8wkOc.png). And [here](http://i.imgur.com/s0ZDyLn.gifv) is another, this time full-screened, .gif of what's happening. [This](http://i.imgur.com/o5WXynp.png) is what the Prefab is, and it contains [this!](http://i.imgur.com/VsIDrRI.png) I'm hoping to provide as much detail as possible to get this solved, I'm stumped. There's 8 total cubes in the exact size of 'Big Cube', I'm basically just wanting 'Big Cube' to be replaced, and fall apart.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that your `smallerCubes` prefab had other cubes inside of it.  What is the position of each of the cubes inside the `smallerCubes` prefab?  I'm guessing that what's happening is that your `explo` prefab is being centered on the position of your original cube, but then your smaller cubes are all positioned relative to `explo`.  So if one of your smaller cubes has a position of (2, 2, 2) inside of your prefab and your prefab gets placed at (1, 1, 1), then your smaller cube will actually be at (3, 3, 3) in world position.

Comment: [Each of the cubes](http://i.imgur.com/upf8YIW.gifv) are .5 in offset, to make it perfectly square with 'Big Cube'. Also, I've noticed a serious [offset](http://i.imgur.com/ptxTIbL.gifv) when dragging the prefab into the instance. Weird?

Comment: Instead of having your SmallerCubes prefab positioned at (5, 2, 3) (or whatever it is) and having your smaller cubes slightly offset from that, position your SmallerCubes prefab at (0, 0, 0), and position all of your smaller cubes slightly offset from that (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), etc.  Actually I don't think the positioning of your SmallerCubes prefab itself matters (only the eight smaller cubes matter), but moving the container too will make it look correct when looking at the prefab.

Comment: @BenRubin [ALMOST!](http://i.imgur.com/54rygNz.gifv). The rotation is resetting and the positioning seems very VERY slightly off. I had no idea that when parented, the children objects have weirdly different offsets.

Comment: Yay.  Change the rotation back to what you had originally before I steered you wrong with the `Quaternion.identity` thing, and you should be good.  The problem was with local space vs. world space.  When you assigned one of your smaller cubes the position (5, 3, 2), you were saying "start from where my parent is and move (5, 3, 2)."  So when you put your explosion where your big cube used to be, the smaller cubes were starting there and moving (5, 3, 2) away.

Comment: After changing 'Quaternion.identity' back to what it was before, I'm gifted with [this](http://i.imgur.com/hPUyLjj.gifv), it's So. Very. Close! The offset of something seems to be just slightly off..

Comment: Hmm it's kind of hard to tell from that screenshot exactly what it's doing.  The only thing I can think of right now is make sure your eight smaller cubes are distributed evenly around (0, 0, 0).  So if your cubes are 1 unit large in each direction, they should be at (0.5, 0.5, 0,5), (-0.5, 0,5, 0.5), and so on.  I'll check in again tomorrow.

Comment: [They all seem to be shifting](http://i.imgur.com/2PsG8QB.gifv) toward their respective positive X directions. And [here](http://i.imgur.com/wC3LEU4.gifv) is ever single smaller cube (parent included) info. Hope you have a good night!

Comment: I think the problem is the positions of your smaller cubes.  The x, y, z values should always be either 0.25 or -0.25, not 0.  To visualize what's happening, imagine you have your large cube at (0, 0, 0) with a size of 1, and a smaller cube inside it at (0.25, 0, 0) with a size of 0.5.  You're standing at (0, 0, 10) looking at the large cube.  Now if the large cube suddenly disappears, you'll see the smaller cube inside which is slightly further away from you because it was at the same position along the z-axis, but it is smaller so it doesn't extend as far towards you.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @BenRubin [Drum roll.](http://i.imgur.com/dvM5Ozx.gifv) Perfect! So it's all relative to the exact center, and not the upper-left of the object. (Maybe I'm used to sprites and lua?) Thanks so very much! How do I throw points at you?

Comment: point point POINTS.  Just kidding.  I'm glad I could help.  I'll summarize what we checked and add that as an answer in case someone else has the same problem and stumbles across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the position of the child cubes in your "explosion" prefab.  From the screenshot and logs that you posted, it looks your prefab is positioned at `(-5.5, -2.4, 3.5)` and the smaller cubes within your prefab are positioned close to that.  When you're looking at your prefab in isolation, it looks fine since all of your smaller cubes are positioned around the center of your prefab.  However, your smaller cubes will retain their prefabbed positions when you instantiate your prefab in your scene.  So if you place your prefab at `(0, 0, 0)` when you're running your game, the child cubes will still positioned nearby `(-5.5, -2.4, 3.5)`.  Positioning all of the small cubes within your prefab relative to `(0, 0, 0)` will make them show up where you expect them to when you instantiate your prefab anywhere in your scene.

Another thing: the line `Debug.Log(explo.transform.position);` is actually showing the position that you assigned to your prefab within the Unity editor, not the position of the prefabbed object that got instantiated within your scene.  To show the position of the object in your scene, store a reference to the instantiated object, and then show the position of that object.  Like this

```
GameObject gameObject = Instantiate(explo, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
Debug.Log(gameObject.transform.position);
```